# Stability of time step for $\frac{dx}{dt} = \mu + \lambda x$.

Tags: numerical-methods, eulers-method

I want to know the time-step $\Delta t$ for which the explicit Euler method is stable.

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \mu + \lambda x.$$

I know for $\mu = 0$ that we need $\Delta t \leq \frac{2}{|\lambda|}$ where $\lambda$ is purely real. But now I want to include a constant $\mu$ (again purely real). How can I find my restriction for $\Delta t$?

I started with applying explicit Euler:
\begin{align*}
x_{i+1} &= x_i + \Delta t (\mu + \lambda x_i)\\
&= x_i(1+\Delta t \lambda) + \Delta t\mu
\end{align*}
The next step would be to apply that $|\frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i}|\leq 1$, however it is not possible to write $x_{i+1} = \nu x_i$ for some $\nu$, how do I have to approach this?

Comment: In this modified equation you are not looking for stable convergence to zero but for stable convergence to the equilibrium value $- \frac{\mu}{\lambda}$. The condition remains the same, $-2<\lambdaΔt\le 0$.

Comment: Why does this condition remains the same? I would assume that $\mu$ has some influence right?

Comment: No, stability is concerned with a difference to the exact solution. In the difference of the equations for the exact and numerical solutions the constant terms cancel.